# Echo from textarea using php

Tags: php, html

I want collect data from a text area and echo using php after removing the first line.I need to add few words along with the data

for example, below php is my php code which processing the text area id `states`

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['states'];
function getLines($text, $start, $end = false)
{
    $devices = explode("\n", $text);

    $output = "";
    foreach ($devices as $key => $line)
    {
        if ($key+1 < $start) continue;
        if ($end && $key+1 > $end) break;
        $output .= $line;
    }
    return $output;
}

echo getLines($_POST['devs'], 2);

?>
```

so If I enter enter below info in my text area

```
United State
Florida
Georgia
Illinois
New York
Texas
```

I will get output like

```
Florida
Georgia
Illinois
New York
Texas
```

I need output like below to suffix the `first line` from `text area` with other text

```
State Florida is in United State
State Georgia is in United State 
State Illinois is in United State
State New York is in United State
State Texas is in United State
```

As per the other answers, I have changed php to add the prefix work `state`

```
function getLines($text, $start, $end = false)
{
    $devices = explode("\n", $text);
    $prefix  = "State ";
    $suffix = echo " in $devices[0]";



    $output = "";
    foreach ($devices as $key => $line)
    {
        if ($key+1 < $start) continue;
        if ($end && $key+1 > $end) break;
        $output .= $prefix.$line.$suffix ;
    }
    return $output;
}

echo getLines($_POST['devs'], 2);


?>
```

But that doesnot working.I can able to add the prefix section alone like 
`$output .= $prefix.$line;`
to get output like below

```
State Florida
```

how can I add the first line along with the echo to show output like

```
State Florida is in United States
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. I had to modify it a little bit because with your pattern I was getting 1 more unneccessery line.

```
$text = "United State
Florida
Georgia
Illinois
New York
Texas
";

function getLines($text, $start, $end = false)
{
    $devices = explode("\n", $text);
    $prefix  = "State ";
    $suffix = " in ". $devices[0]."<br>";

    $output = "";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($devices as $key => $line)
    {
        $i++;
        if ($key+1 < $start) continue;
        if ($i != count($devices)) {
        $output .= $prefix.$line.$suffix;
        }
    }
    return trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $output));
}

echo getLines($text, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I see  `State Florida` in one line and  `in United State` in another line. can i get them in single line like `State Florida in United State`  ?

Comment: Have you copy paste my code ? because if I run this code I get this output: http://prntscr.com/1jbhbq

Comment: @ DeiForm       I am using exactly the same code.only difference is I am using `$text = $_POST['devs'];` to collect my input data from my form   http://prntscr.com/1jbioc

Comment: Dont you have there some extra styling or something ? Beacuse raw new file with this code works ok

Comment: Also could you make printscreen or paste here output html of your file ?

Comment: @ DeiForm      http://jsfiddle.net/2kAYu/  here is my html code. and there no other styling

Comment: Well it is really odd. I pasted your code here http://phpfiddle.org/ and it output me as you wanted. Try to make new file with just form and php and then add your classes and you will see

Comment: @ DeiForm      I just edited my code to display the output in text area rather than in html. and I see an additional `<br />` adding into it which making a separate. I really dont know from where the line break is adding up :(   http://prntscr.com/1jcdcq   you have any clue ?

Comment: Well the additional BR does not come from the function. I was testing it in clear document.

Comment: Ok, now I copied your code from that fiddle and it is working properly. Paste here fiddle link again if you have there some JS or styles.

Comment: I am working on wordpress platform. may be wordpress code adding it.. I see few discussion on this topics..Thank you very much for your extended support on this. Accepting your answer. :)

Comment: OK, thanks, I made one edit in my answer. I delete the new lines from returned output. Try it now